# Azure Logic Apps - Calling a secured end point (TLS)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a C# component that calls a secured end point (TLS 1.2). As I am exploring the options of moving this component to Azure (Logic Apps) how do I add the security protocol header information to the HTTP request. I could add the header information like 'Content_Type' etc but not really sure of adding the security protocol info to header and couldn't find much helpful articles. Thanks in advance for the helpful hints.

My outgoing HTTP Request:

```
{
    "uri": "https://xxxx/v3/oauth2/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content_Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client_secret": "5xxxxxxxxxx9",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "password": "MyPassword2018",
        "username": "email@company.com"
    }
}
```

C# code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication#certificate-authentication

Comment: Is this a relatively standard SOAP or RESTFul endpoint?  Maybe you don't have to do anything.  Calling a TLS 1.2 endpoint is supported OOB and is not something that would be set in a header property.

Comment: Hi Johns-305, You are correct..I am able to call the RESTful endpoint without any specification about the security protocol. I was getting a vague error earlier which I thought was because of the protocol being not specified but it turned out to be the encoding in the client secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logic apps which need to talk to oauth protected endpoints we typically call an Azure function. In addition to having a C# solution which will let you leverage working code, you would also be able to secure your credentials in key vault instead of having them in plain text in your logic app action.